# How would I create a gradle property with two values?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I want to pass property for my Gradle project in command line. But this property has two values for example:

Let's say that I pass the property something like this

```
gradle myTask -Pexclude=xxxxx,yyyyy
```

Above, I have passed two values in the property exclude. What exclude does is that it excludes the two files from the build process. But I am confused that these comma separated format would work or not. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using the `-P` flag you're actually setting a property with a **String** value, i.e. the value of the `exclude` property in your example will be set to `xxxxx,yyyyy`.

If you'd like to convert this value into an Array you can simply use `split()`, i.e. `def excludeArr = exclude.split(",")`

Comment: Thank you! Also, If suppose I have the property 'exclude' already defined in build.gradle file  then would this redefinition of 'exclude' via command line OVERRIDES the property value in build.gradle or append to it?

Comment: You have it as a property of a [SourceSet](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html) object (also check [The Java Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) chapter in gradle user guide). However, you will need to use the property provided in the command line in order to set it.